# Export configuration of oracle database?

Tags: xml, json, database, oracle

how can I export only the configuration data from our database schema maybe into a JSON or XML file? Mainly for comparison purposes for staging and production?

Comment: What "configuration data" are you talking about?  If you are talking about the pfile or spfile (depending on what you use to start the database), I'd just compare those files across the environments.  If you want the parameters that are actually set in the environment (i.e. including changes that have been made since startup that haven't been reflected in the pfile) you can query v$parameter.  Otherwise, there is lots of "configuration data" that you might be interested in.

Comment: something that would automatically show all the changes made to the data in database

Comment: That sounds like the opposite of what I'd think of when you're talking about "configuration data".  If you're trying to track changes to data in user-defined tables, triggers with a log table would be the simplest approach.  If you just want to compare data across environments, you can create a database link between the two databases and run queries across the database link (i.e. `select * from table_a minus select * from table_a@remote_db`).

Comment: how would I select from remote db? how do i put in the username port host etc